# Problem running a python function against a pandas dataframe and returning values into the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, geocode

I've got a list of over 1mm lat/long pairs that I'm looking to reverse geocode using the [reverse-geocoder](https://github.com/thampiman/reverse-geocoder) library.  I've got my dataframe set up with columns for lat, long, and a pair which I constructed as (lat, long).

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pandas as pdimport reverse_geocoder as rg

df = pd.read_csv ('reverse.csv')
```

This provides a dataframe:

```
      Unnamed:  0      email        lat     long
   0      1            a@email.com  42.36   -71.07  
   1      2            b@email.com  37.72   -122.44 
   2      3            c@email.com  40.83   -74.25
   3      4            d@email.com  41.70   -70.22
   4      5            f@email.com  34.27   -118.71
```

Realizing I need a few more columns, I add the following:

```
df['reversePair'] = list(zip(df.lat, df.long))
```

Which creates a datacolumn and has values such as `(42.36, -71.07)`

I then added additional columns:

```
df=df.assign(city="")
df=df.assign(state="")
df=df.assign(country="")
```

All's well up to this point.  I then try to run the function row by row (there has to be a better way, especially since the package can take multiple tuples but I've struggled at this point already):

*(Note for the below, limiting to two records for example purposes)*

```
import itertools

n = 2

for item in itertools.islice(df['reversePair'], n):
    print(item) 
    x = rg.search(item)
    for i in x:
        print(i["name"])
        print(i["admin1"])
        print(i["cc"])
    
        df["city"] = i["name"]
        df["state"] = i["admin1"]
        df["country"] = i["cc"]
    
df.head(2)
```

This then gives me the following correct results, but in the dataset it is only adding (overwriting?) the **last value returned** into both records.  It's driving me crazy.

```
    (42.36, -71.07)
    Boston
    Massachusetts
    US
    (37.72, -122.44)
    Daly City
    California
    US
      Unnamed: 0    email       lat     long    city    reversePair state     country
   0    1.0     a@email.com 42.36   -71.07  Daly City   (42.36, -71.07)   California    US
   1    2.0     b@email.com 37.72   -122.44 Daly City   (37.72, -122.44)  California    US
```

Row 0 should be city = Boston, state = Massachusetts, country = US (it is, but assuming it's from the wrong record).

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong with this would be much appreciated.  Also, if anyone can see a way to make it faster, that would also be very much appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at each loop you assign the value to the full column as you don't select which row. To fix, it would be something like `df.loc[idx, "city"] = i["name"]`, where `idx` would be the index value of the row of the `item` (except you don't extract it currently).

Anyway, I don't have the library installed, but of what I read on the link provided, I believe you can do without a loop `for`, directly pass all the coordinates couples in `rg.search`.

```
# create a dataframe from the result of rg.search
res = pd.DataFrame(
    # you can pass a tuple of several two coordinates tuple at once
    rg.search(tuple(df['reversePair'].tolist())), 
    # use the same index than df for later join or column assignation
    index=df.index)
print(res.head()) # to have an idea of what it is
```

Then you can either

```
# use join if column's names don't matter too much
new_df = df.join(res[['name','admin1','cc']])
```

or

```
# just add the column with the name you wanted
df['city'] = res['name']
df['state'] = res['admin1']
df["country"] = res["cc"]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to run your initial code block but got an error of `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`.

Comment: @grega one raison could be some lat or long are missing, does `df.loc[df['reversePair'].str.len()<2]` return any rows?

Comment: No.  All rows have values.  None have empty strings, either.